# NSolve doesn't work on an equation containing a numerical integral and constraints

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

I'm having trouble getting *Mathematica* to solve equations numerically. I know that its important to specify the type of variables for pattern testing (see e.g. [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502)) but this doesn't seem to work. Consider the following example:

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a x, {x, 0, 1}]
NSolve[f[0.5 + b] == 1, b]
NSolve[f[0.5 + b] == 1, b, Reals]
NSolve[f[0.5 + b] == 1 && 0 < b < 3, b]
```

The first one is evaluated (according to a warning message using inverse functions) but the second and third are returned unevaluated. How can I get these to run?

Comment: Both `FindRoot` and `FindInstance` work in place of `NSolve` with the extra conditions. Of course, they won't find *all* solutions automatically, so this is still interesting.

Comment: Honestly I am surprised that `NSolve` worked at all in *any* of those cases! In my understanding, `NSolve` is tailored towards explicitly linear and polynomial equations. I don't really know what it does when confronted with the numerical function `f`, whose structure is entirely unknown. I suspect that `NSolve` switches solution method when constraints are present, and those methods simply don't know how to deal with the `f` "black box".

Comment: @MarcoB. Yes it's strange: if you `Trace` them, you always see the sequence `{f[0.5 +b], {NumericQ[0.5 +b], False}, f[0.5 +b]}, f[0.5 +b]==1`, but for some reason `NSolve` continues on the first one.

Comment: @MarcoB, march, try `InverseFunction[f][1.]`.  Apparently `NSolve` will try inverse functions, but only for (presumed) analytic functions.  It does seem like an fairly elementary step.